# How to make my home page screen fit without scrolling

Tags: html, css, screen, bigcartel

I use a bigcartel type of theme for my website where I can edit CSS and some other pieces.

Here is the website: www.allect.com

What I want is the homepage to fit into the screen size without having to scroll to the bottom.

Like this website (www.representclo.com)

Would anyone be able to help me please?

Thanks

Comment: `html,body{overflow:hidden;}` ????

Answer (score 0):

In my idea you may be thinking of setting a default minimum height and width for the page but that's just what I'm thinking what you're saying.

Try:

```
body{
min-height: 500px;
min-width: 500px;
max-height: 1000px;
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to insert this piece of code. Is it in the CSS?

Comment: Yes in the body section of it

Comment: Thank you. I have just applied what your code. Please re visit the website and see the effect is has had. www.allect.com

Comment: It still does not fit into the screen without scrolling :(

Comment: You're welcome and I am not too sure if that was the effect you wanted but if you do need help with CSS and HTMl then email me at oggeri555@outlook.com and by the way what service do you use to edit your website?

Comment: You could always either make a zoom-in and out or make the elements smaller

Answer (score 0):

Check this page out:
[CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html)

> CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer
>
> Sometimes things that
>   used to be really simple with tables can still appear pretty hard with
>   CSS. This layout for instance would consist of 3 cells; two with a
>   fixed height, and a third one in the center filling up the remaining
>   space. Using CSS, however, you have to take a different approach...

Answer (score 0):

in short: your main div element with id wrap (ie **#wrap**) is computed in one of your scripts to a total size wich is always breater then the window size

because your website is minified, please check your **source code** for the selector of this element and fix it's computing formula